# Script A calls Script B and Script B has parms

Tags: bash

Using BASH, I have `script_a.sh` which calls `script_B.sh`and `script_b.sh` 
has parms.

I found [this OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352851/how-to-call-shell-script-from-another-shell-script) to be useful but my results aren't what I'm expecting.

```
$cat script_a.sh 
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT_PATH="./script_b.sh"
("$SCRIPT_PATH")
exit 0

$ cat script_b.sh 
#!/bin/bash
LICENSE_BEGIN=`date --date="$1 day ago" +%y%m%d`
LICENSE_EXPIR=`date --date="$2 day ago" +%y%m%d`

echo "BEGIN  DATE $LICENSE_BEGIN"
echo "EXIPRE DATE $LICENSE_EXPIR"

exit 0
```

**Script Results**

```
./script_b.sh  90 3
BEGIN  DATE 181209
EXIPRE DATE 190306

./script_a.sh 90 3
BEGIN  DATE 190308
EXIPRE DATE 190308
```

How can I get `script_a`  to accept parms and return the same results as `script_b` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass the list of positional parameters as `"$@"`:

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT_PATH="./script_b.sh"
"$SCRIPT_PATH" "$@"
```

(I removed an additional subshell from around the invocation)

From the `SPECIAL PARAMETERS` section of `man bash`:

> ```
>    @      Expands to the positional parameters, starting from  one.   When
>           the  expansion  occurs  within  double  quotes,  each  parameter
>           expands to a separate word.  That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1"
>           "$2"  ...
> ```